# How make .swf file is as link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, hyperlink, flash, swfobject

I use .swf file in may site:

```
<div>
    <object width="100%" height="100%">
    <embed  src="@Url.Content( "~/Content/TopRight.swf" )"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="310" height="95"></embed>
    </object>
</div>
```

And I want when click this banner, opens any link (any page). I placed `<object>` into `<a>` tag, but nothings changed. How can I do this?

Comment: Put a transparent button that occupies all height and wight, all of this inside the flash, in a topper layer. The add the action with url to the transparent button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this at the end of your code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var hit = new MovieClip();
hit.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
hit.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
var clicky = new SimpleButton(null,null,null,hit);
this.addChild(clicky);

clicky.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"));  
});
```

should work :)

Comment: Sorry, where should I put this exactly?  to .cshtml file?

Comment: Today, when i read this I'm thinking my answer may need a little tweaking. are you placing the file into your html site and wanting the link to be in the html, but fed to the swf? if so that's easy, i'll just tweak what i gave you.. If you simply want to hardcode your URL you're good here. Place this anywhere in your FLA file. If you're using other code put it at the bottom. Dynamically creates a clear button the size of your stage, then when clicked goes to where ever, in this case, google. Let me know if i can help!